# How to remove Create an Account button on Success Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, order-success-page

I want to remove **Create An Account** button with **"You can track your order status by creating an account."** text on success page in Magento 2.
I have removed `checkout.registration` block from `checkout_onepage_success.xml` but it is still showing.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
       <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="success.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
       <!--<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Registration" name="checkout.registration" template="registration.phtml" cacheable="false"/>-->
</referenceContainer>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Flush cache. and re-order. it works for me fine.

Answer (score 3):

In your custom theme add the XML file below:

**app/design/THEME/NAME/Magento_Checkout/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.registration" remove="true"/>
</page>
```

Comment: I did not removed this block , but it is not showing in successpage

Comment: The answer is missing a `<body>` tag wrapping the `<referenceBlock>` tag. It might help somebody.